# Add/Subtract Selected Value from Integer

Tags: jquery, math, integer

I'm quite new to jquery. I've made extensive use of what i've been able to find and understand. However, i'm not sure at all how to tackle this particular problem.

I have an integer that manifests as a DOM string in html. Using Jquery, i've set up a contextual menu that displays the numbers +1->+10, and -1->-10. I'm looking for a way to add/subtract the value of an entry of the contextual menu, from the initial integer.

For example, i have the initial integer 100, i right click on it, revealing the contextual menu. I go to the -5, and click it. The integer changes to 95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've given your initial integer an ID, you could do the following in the context-menu click handler:
`$('#integer').html(parseInt($('#integer').html())-numberClicked)`

Comment: what about if i want the entry in the contextual menu to call a method on the integer object? (that isn't +/-. This is more a syntax question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt to parse your string to a int, and then it's just simple +/-/*

```
alert(parseInt('12') + 4);
```